# Javascript check if items in an array are consecutive

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Say I have an array which holds the values [1,2,3,6,7].

How can I check the array to see if it holds 3 consecutive numbers. For example, the array above holds [1,2,3] so this would return false in my function.

```
        var currentElement = null;
        var counter = 0;

        //check if the array contains 3 or more consecutive numbers:
        for (var i = 0; i < bookedAppArray.length; i++) {
            if ((bookedAppArray[i] != currentElement) && (bookedAppArray[i] === bookedAppArray[i - 1] + 1)) {

                if (counter > 2) {
                    return true;
                }

                currentElement = bookedAppArray[i];
                counter++;
            } else {
                counter = 1;
            }
        }

        if(counter > 2){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: _"How can I check the array to see if it holds 3 consecutive numbers. For example, the array above holds [1,2,3] so this would return false in my function."_ Three consecutive of _same_ number ?

Comment: You want to return FALSE if it *does* contain three consecutive numbers? That seems the wrong way around.

Comment: maybe 3 and 6 should return false?

Comment: @guest271314 no, for examples, [1,2,3] or [9,8,7] ect.

Comment: Three consecutive of _any_ number ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, any 3 consecutive numbers.

Comment: May I ask, just to save myself the repeated typing, that people providing an answer *explain their answer*, that way people can understand what's going on, learn something from it and use that understanding to apply the demonstrated techniques in other situations? Unexplained black-box "do this" code doesn't help anyone outside of a very specific, and limited, situation.

Comment: @nicomp my attempt so far as been added.

Comment: @CottonSocksBro Any three consecutive numbers should return `false` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution

- checks wheater the length of the array is greater than `2`,
- iterates over the array from position 2
- gets the difference between position 2 and 1 before the index,
- checks if the absolute difference is `1`
- checks the difference between position 1 before and at the index is equal the difference,
- and if so, it returns false, because consecutive elements are found.
- if not, increment index by `1`

```js
function consecutive(array) {
    var i = 2, d;
    while (i < array.length) {
        d = array[i - 1] - array[i - 2];
        if (Math.abs(d) === 1 && d === array[i] - array[i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}

document.write(consecutive([1]) + '<br>');             // true
document.write(consecutive([2, 4, 6]) + '<br>');       // true
document.write(consecutive([9, 8, 7]) + '<br>');       // false
document.write(consecutive([1, 2, 3, 6, 7]) + '<br>'); // false
document.write(consecutive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) + '<br>'); // false
```

Comment: how come the last example is false? 1,2,3,4,5 shouldn't return true?

Comment: @AndreiPrãdan, it is consecutive and it should return `false` if so.

Comment: oh, I re-read the initial question... it's a little bit counterintuitive to call consecutive() and receive false when it's actually consecutive, but got it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed to do the same, and came up with this function, if someone sees it useful.

```js
assert(!Array.prototype.isConsecutive, 'Array.isConsecutive rewriting conflict');
/**
 * Check if array consist of consecutive numbers
 * @param {number} [startFrom] If array should start from a specific number
 * @returns {Boolean} true if array consist of consecutive numbers
 */
Array.prototype.isConsecutive = /** @lends Array */ function (startFrom) {
  let curVal;
  if (startFrom !== undefined) curVal = startFrom - 1;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
  return this.every((n) => (
    !Number.isNaN(n)
    && (curVal = (curVal === undefined ? n : curVal + 1))
    && n === curVal)) || false;
};
```

It returns `true` if array is consecutive (more intuitive this way), you can add `!` if you need a reverse.
Here are some tests for it:

```js
  it('Array.isConsecutive', () => {
    expect([1, 2, 3, 4].isConsecutive()).to.be.true;
    expect([1, 2, 3, 4].isConsecutive(1)).to.be.true;
    expect([5, 6, 7, 8].isConsecutive()).to.be.true;
    expect([6, 5, 7, 8, 9].isConsecutive()).to.be.false;
    expect([1, 2, 3, 4].isConsecutive(2)).to.be.false;
  });
```

PS. there are some ani-patterns (no assign and no prototype internal functions) in my example (I'm sure some dudes will dislike my answer), but I don't care, you can convert it into a function if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking logically, this should be as easy as iterating over the array, and just checking the two indices previous to the current one.

Just adding `1` to the previous index, and `2` to the one before that one, and they should all be equal, something like this

```
function hasThree(arr) {
    var res = false;

    arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
        var l1 = arr[index - 1], // get previous
            l2 = arr[index - 2]; // get the one before the previous

        if ( l1 && l2 ) { // if two previous exist

            // add 1, and then 2, and see if all are equal

            if ( item === l1 + 1 && item === l2 + 2 ) res = true;
        }
    });

    return res;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hv6cy8v7/)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.  Here is my attempt.

```
function cons(ar) {

    var cnt = 0;

    ar.forEach(function (i, idx) {
        if (idx > 0) {
            if (i == (ar[idx - 1] + 1)){
                cnt++;
            }
            else {
                if (cnt < 2)
                    cnt = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    return cnt < 2;
}

console.log('expected true', cons([1, 2, 5, 6, 9]));
console.log('expected false', cons([0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]));
console.log('expected false', cons([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one. Just make sure to sort the array before doing it

```
function checkIfConsecutive(Arr) {
          let isCnsc = true;
          for (st in Arr ) {
               if ( Arr[parseInt(st)+1]-Arr[parseInt(st)] > 1 && !isNaN(Arr[parseInt(st)+1]-Arr[parseInt(st)] )) {
                    isCnsc = false;
               }
          }
           return isCnsc;
     }
```

Comment: you might not even need IsNaN chek - i added it just in case but i am lazy to try it out now :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `Array.prototype.some()` , `Array.prototype.filter()`

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7];
var arr2 = [1, 2, "a", 3];
var check = function(a) {
  // for each element in array `a` 
  return !a.some(function(item, index) { 
    // slice next three elements, including current element `item` from `a` array
    var next = a.slice(index, 3);
    console.log(next);
    // if next three items in array `a` are type `Number`
    // return `false`, else return `true`
    return next.filter(Number).length === 3 ? true : false
  })
};
// each item in `arr1` returns `false` , where item is followed
// by two numbers
// `arr2` returns `true` , where item is not followed by two numbers
console.log(check([1,2,3]), check(arr1), check(arr2)) // `false`, `false`, `true`
```

---

Alternatively, using `for` loop , `Array.prototype.every()`

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7];
var arr2 = [1, 2, "a", 3];
var check = function(a) {
  var res;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // if `a[i]` is followed by two numbers, return `false`
    if (a.slice(i, 3).every(function(n) {
      return typeof n === "number"
    })) {
      res = false;
      break;
    } 
    // if `a[i]` is not followed by two numbers, return `true`
    else {
      res = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return res
}
console.log(check([1,2,3]), check(arr1), check(arr2)) // `false`, `false` , `true`
```

Comment: What's it supposed to do? Have you even tested it? If yes, then can you explain why does it always return true, except for a completely empty array?