# Check if array elements has same magnitude

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and what I want to do with this if to check if all the elements has the same magnitude for example:

- array [40, 20, 30, 10] has 10 as magnitude so output should be true
- array [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] has 1 as magnitude so output should be true
- array [2, 6, 12, 20] has more than one magnitude so output should be false

The could should be work with integers and floats, incluiding negative numbers.

What I tried is to use some code from here but seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257152/javascript-check-if-items-in-an-array-are-consecutive) only works for consecutive numbers and if there are repeated x times. So I wonder if this code can be addapted to fix my problem or if there is another way to solve it.

Code:

```
function consecutive(array) {
    var i = 2, d;
    while (i < array.length) {
        d = array[i - 1] - array[i - 2];
        if (Math.abs(d) === 1 && d === array[i] - array[i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}

var array = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3]; // Return true
// var array = [194, 54, 23, 7, 3, 6, 8 ] //Example 2 Return false 
console.log(consecutive(array));
```

Comment: You phrased the question with `same magnitude/difference` but magnitude and difference are not the same thing. Do you just want all items to form a linear sequence (perhaps not in order) like `[11, 9, 10, 8]`? Or is a list like `[1, 3, 5]` the same *magnitude* because they fit in a category like all equal `log10`?

Comment: @Mark Sorry about that I want the magnitude. The elements can be in order or not. For example, 1, 3, 5 has magnitude 2 and output should be true, but the array can be 5, 1, 3 and I expect the same result.

Comment: What should  `[ 1, -1, 2 ]` return?

Comment: @Matt In this case false, maybe if a 0 is in that array then the result should be true

Comment: @User1899289003 you lost me with the 0 :) Can you define "magnitude" in more detail? Maybe how you are calculating a magnitude for some of the arrays in the question?

Comment: I read it as [order of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) but that looks wrong from the examples

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the trick...

```js
// array [40, 20, 30, 10] has 10 as magnitude so output should be true
// array [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] has 1 as magnitude so output should be true
// array [2, 6, 12, 20] has more than one magnitude so output should be false

const arr1 = [40, 20, 30, 10];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
const arr3 = [2, 6, 12, 20];

const magnitude = items => {
  const unique = [...new Set(items)];
  const sorted = unique.sort((a,b) => a-b);
  const mags = [];
  
  sorted.forEach((item, idx) => {
    if (idx + 1 >= sorted.length) return null;
    const next = sorted[idx + 1];
    
    mags.push(item - next);
  });

  return [...new Set(mags)].length <= 1;
};

console.log('arr1', magnitude(arr1));
console.log('arr2', magnitude(arr2));
console.log('arr3', magnitude(arr3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
const arr1 = [40.10, 20.10, 30.10, 10.10, 50.20];

const arr2 = [40.10, 20.10, 30.10, 10.10, 50.10];

const arr3 = [40, 20, 30, 10, 50];


const hasSameMagnitue = (values: number[]): boolean => {
    const sortByOrder = values.sort();

    const diff = sortByOrder.slice(0, -1).map((el, index) => (sortByOrder[index + 1] - el).toFixed(2));

    const result = diff.every((el) => el === diff[0]);

    return result;
}


console.log('hasSameMagnitue', hasSameMagnitue(arr1)); // false

console.log('hasSameMagnitue', hasSameMagnitue(arr2)); // true

console.log('hasSameMagnitue', hasSameMagnitue(arr3)); // true
```