# How can I filter the array of objects by: if object ids are consective

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JSON file with data inside.
I have to filter the data by : if user has more than two names, and if user ids are consecutive.
The JSON file :

```
[
{
"_id": "62bd5fba34a8f1c90303055c",
"index": 0,
"email": "mcdonaldholden@xerex.com",
"nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Wendi Mooney"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Holloway Whitehead"
  }
]
},
{
"_id": "62bd5fbac3e5a4fca5e85e81",
"index": 1,
"nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Janine Barrett"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Odonnell Savage"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Patty Owen"
  }
]
}, ...
```

I have managed to find an a solution to filter if the users have more than two names : `userData.filter((names,i) => { return names?.nameList?.filter(names => { return names.name;}).length > 2 ; })`
But I cant seem to grasp myself around the concept of filtering the consecutive ids.
Also I was advised to not use any for loops at all. Only ES6 array loops like map, forEach and filter.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Output all the objects that meet the criteria : More than two users and its ids are consecutive.

Comment: so, some objects in nameList can have id but no name?

Comment: Pretty much not, all objects in nameList have and id and a name.

Comment: if you can find a function to check if an array has consecutive numbers then you have almost solved it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257152/javascript-check-if-items-in-an-array-are-consecutive . then inside the filter add a && condition with `isConsecutive(namesList.map(n =>n.id))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `every()` to compare the ID of every element with the previous ID:

```
const result = data.filter(({nameList}) =>
  nameList.length > 2 &&
  nameList.every(({id}, i, a) => !i || id === a[i - 1].id + 1)
);
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
  "_id": "62bd5fba34a8f1c90303055c",
  "index": 0,
  "email": "mcdonaldholden@xerex.com",
  "nameList": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Wendi Mooney"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Holloway Whitehead"
  }]
}, {
  "_id": "62bd5fbac3e5a4fca5e85e81",
  "index": 1,
  "nameList": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Janine Barrett"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Odonnell Savage"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Patty Owen"
  }]
}];

const result = data.filter(({nameList}) =>
  nameList.length > 2 &&
  nameList.every(({id}, i, a) => !i || id === a[i - 1].id + 1)
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work perfectly. Also one of my staff did suggest using .some() and it matches it perfectly!

Comment: Updated to use `every()`. Feels better than `!some()`.

Comment: was just about to suggest `every` ... but I almost posted a similar answer, like `nameList.length > 2 && nameList.slice(1).every(({ id }, index) => id === nameList[index].id + 1)`